# To find the value that represents the a specific total in a sequence of sums in SQLite

Tags: sql, sum

I have created the following table `turns`:

```
CREATE TABLE "turns" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "weight"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "turn"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```

This is what the table looks like:

[image: table turns]

I am trying to retrieve the name of the person at which point the sum of weights = 1000

which in this case is `Chillwell` (or 'chill' as it says in the image)

I have written the following

```
Select name from turns where weight = (select sum(weight) from turns where sum(weight) = 1000);
```

It's throwing up a misuse error

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: misuse of aggregate: sum()
At line 1:
Select name from turns where weight = (select sum(weight) from turns where sum(weight) = 1000);
```

Can you give me some advice about this?

Comment: You should post the data instead of the images

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(weight) over (order by turn) as running_weight
      from turns t
     ) t
where running_weight >= 1000 and running_weight - weight < 1000
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work when I applied it to another code editor. I got a syntax error near "("